# Kubernetes and akka application

Tags: java, kubernetes, akka

I have a vendor product that has services external to Kubernetes.  The application calls a web service on a pod and then the pod calls a service external to Kubernetes.  When transferring data the external machine calls back on a different port to open a stream.  It fails, when tracking this down I found that the service is calling the node and not the pod.  The vendor is using the https://akka.io Akka to talk to each other.  What the external is doing is not calling back the pod correctly and the node is the destination.  Some of the folks involved think it could be an Akka problem, while others believe it could be routing.  From what I see looking at Wireshark results is that the callback should be able to contact the pod that called it.  But I am not sure on which way to go.  Anyone who can guide with some pointers would be helpful.

Comment: How does the external service know about where to call back? "calling the node and not the pod" what does that mean? The external service will have to be told explicitly how to call back exactly (e.g. an URL that's accessible externally). What is likely to fail, is just taking the original address of a client and trying to open up connection to a different port. That assumes that all machines are in the same routable IP network which is not a valid assumption in most situations but certainly not in a Kubernetes environment or any other environment with private nat'd networks.

Comment: I believe you are correct.  It is calling back the original ip which is the node.  That confirms my suspicion, and with at least someone else saying the same, I feel better.  Thank you.